# Mocking a cookie in react-cookie

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I'm trying to set a cookie in my test to make sure it's getting cleared out in my component:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

test('successfully logs the user out', async () => {
  const cookie = new Cookies()
  cookie.set('authtoken', 'some-token')
  const { getByText } = render(<Logout/>)
})
```

But in my Logout component the cookies object is empty:

```
export default function Logout() {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['authtoken'])
  console.log(cookies)
}
```

Is there another way to do this? Preferably one that isn't passing the cookie as a prop.

Comment: I don't know the inner working of those two packages, but it seems like you are trying to use 2 different cookie packages; react-cookie and universal-cookie. If you are using ssr use the first, else the second. Do you have any more context that may help?

Comment: @Devin One package has a dependency on the other. It's really a `react-cookie` question I think.

Comment: Cookies in react cookie are provided contextually. Is it possible your cookie is not being provided because the cookie provider is not being rendered? Docs example export default function Root() {
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <App />
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
}

Comment: @Devin I tried putting `<CookiesProvider>` in the `render` method too. But still no dice.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was what @Oleg and @Devin were hinting at. To render the provider as well. But I also had to pass the `cookies` as parameter like so:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

test('successfully logs the user out', async () => {
  const cookie = new Cookies({authtoken: 'some-token'});
  const { getByText } = render(
    <CookiesProvider cookies={cookie}>
      <Router>
        <Logout/>
      </Router>
    </CookiesProvider>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding

```
 const cookie = new Cookies();
 cookie.HAS_DOCUMENT_COOKIE = false;
```

Comment: The `cookies` object in the `Logout` component is still empty unfortunately

Comment: Look at examples for more use cases: https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/master/packages/universal-cookie/src/__tests__/Cookies-test.js

Comment: Try without hook, cookie.get

Comment: Yeah, `console.log(document.cookie)` is also empty. Probably a hook thing. But there must be some way to do this no?

Comment: Try like document.cookie = 'test=' + cookieValue;

Comment: That works. The cookie is passed over to the component. But the `cookies` object is still empty

Comment: For mockup may be you can make single tone for this object and export

Comment: Not sure what that means

Comment: export const cookie; and import in login

Comment: I rather not write code specifically to get my test passing

Comment: Try with <CookiesProvider> like in example : https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/master/packages/react-cookie/src/__tests__/useCookies-test.js

Comment: Already did. But finally got it working by doing `<CookiesProvider cookies={cookie}>`, where `cookie` is the cookie object

Answer (score 0):

According to react-cookie, you can access the cookies directly using the DOM.

```
 document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(c) {
    document.cookie = c
      .replace(/^ +/, '')
      .replace(/=.*/, '=;expires=' + new Date().toUTCString() + ';path=/');
 });
```

This function is to clear cookies.

Something else that I was thinking in an earlier comment was that you render the component with cookies via "

```
const cookied = withCookies(<Login />)
render(cookied)
```

"

A link to this information and it's context can be found at: https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/master/packages/universal-cookie/src/utils.ts

Comment: This should be the same as `document.cookie='foo'` no? Tried it as well and no dice unfortunately

Comment: Seems like according to the docs `withCookies` sets some props on the component, which is not what I want. Tried as well and still no luck

Comment: Well, i'm working on my own ssr application. I'm going to integrate cookies at the global level right now. I'll let you know if I run into this problem or why it works if I don't.

Comment: See my answer for the solution. It's not really ideal though as all I'm doing is passing in the cookie so it's available in the component.